# How to fire event on only one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 elements with the same class: `.tip-container`

And I want to fire an event on `mouseenter` but only in the hovered element.

I have this html:

```
<div class="personal_info_form">
  <div class="form-group">        
    <span class="information-sign"></span>
    <div class="tip-container hidden">
      <div class="tip">Phone: 7777777777</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">        
    <span class="information-sign"></span>
    <div class="tip-container hidden">
      <div class="tip">Email: hola@hello.com</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">        
    <span class="information-sign"></span>
    <div class="tip-container hidden">
      <div class="tip">Address: this is the address</div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have this js:

```
Drupal.behaviors.personalInfo = (function(){
    var _attach = function(context){
            $('.personal_info_form', context)
            //.once()
            .each(function(i, section){
                new PersonalInfo($(section));
            });
    };

    return {
            attach: _attach
    };
})();

function PersonalInfo($el){
    this.$el = $el;
    this.infoSign = this.$el.find('.information-sign');
    this.tipContainer = this.$el.find('.tip-container');
    this.toggleInfoSign();
    return this;
}

PersonalInfo.prototype.toggleInfoSign = function(){
    var THIS = this;
    $(THIS.infoSign).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            THIS.tipContainer.removeClass('hidden');
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            THIS.tipContainer.addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

    return THIS;
};
```

The tip container is hidden by default, so when you hover the `span` with the class `information-sign` the `tip-container` `div` should be shown or hidden when the mouse leave.
For now, when you hover on any of the `.information-sign` `span`s, the other hidden elements shows up.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think CSS would be a better option - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bscsjdad/)

This should give you a basic idea of what is needed:

```
.tip-container.hidden {
  display: none;
}
span.information-sign {
  position: relative;
}
span.information-sign:hover + .tip-container.hidden {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not calling `new PersonalInfo` on each section, you're just calling it on the whole form. So `this.$el.find('.tip-container')` returns all the `.tip-container` DIVs, not just a single one.

```
Drupal.behaviors.personalInfo = (function(){
    var _attach = function(context){
            $('.personal_info_form .form-group', context)
            //.once()
            .each(function(i, section){
                new PersonalInfo($(section));
            });
    };

    return {
            attach: _attach
    };
})();
```